# Adding nodes to pipe ends using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, nodes

I have two features, a pipe distribution network, and nodes. I need to have nodes at the end of each pipe. I have already found which pipes have no nodes at their ends.

How can I add nodes to the end of the pipes that have no nodes?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

Comment: Have you tried building a geometric network and look at the network_junction featureclass?

Answer (score 1):

Select the pipes with no nodes, then use this layer as the input into Feature Vertices to Points.  Ensure that you are only exporting the start and end vertices.  Combine this output with your existing Nodes feature class.

Comment: I have done that successfully. But I am trying to merge the created nodes with my existing nodes using merge, but it is not working. Ideas on how to combine them both?

Comment: That is a different question for GIS SE so you should post that as a different question but... you can start an edit session on the target feature class, select the vertices from the newly created ends, copy and past from the edit dropdown menu.  You will be prompted to confirm the past into the target featureclass.

Comment: I used the Union tool to combine both features, and it works fine. Thank you for your help.